# Why does Core Data fetch request return empty from custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-data

I have a method in ViewController.m called getData which is called inside viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)getData {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WorkoutHasExercise" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"exerciseName", @"reps", @"sets", nil];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(workoutName = %@)", _workoutName];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if ([objects count] == 0) {

    } else {
        [_exercises removeAllObjects];
        for (int x = 0; x < [objects count]; x++) {
            matches = objects[x];
            [_exercises addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"exerciseName"]];
            [_totalSets addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"sets"]];
            [_totalReps addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"reps"]];
            [_currentSets addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
        }
    }
    [_exercisesTableView reloadData];

}
```

I also have a custom UITableViewCell with two buttons initiated in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
ActiveWorkoutCell *cell = (ActiveWorkoutCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActiveWorkoutCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

cell.increaseButton.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.decreaseButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

In ActiveWorkoutCell.m I have 2 IBActions for the buttons:

```
- (IBAction)decreaseSets:(id)sender {
    ActiveWorkoutViewController *vc = [[ActiveWorkoutViewController alloc] init];
    [vc decreaseSets:[sender tag]];
}

- (IBAction)increaseSets:(id)sender {
    ActiveWorkoutViewController *vc = [[ActiveWorkoutViewController alloc] init];
    [vc increaseSets:[sender tag]];
}
```

The IBActions call these 2 methods back in ViewController.m

```
-(void)increaseSets:(NSInteger)row {
    [self getData];
    //There will be code here to increase the value of currentSets[row]
}

-(void)decreaseSets:(NSInteger)row {
    [self getData]
    //Code to decrease value...
}
```

PROBLEM:

When getData is called from viewDidLoad, it works fine.
The problem occurs when returning to ViewController.m from the IBAction in ActiveWorkoutCell.m.
When I call [self getData] in increaseSets the fetch request returns an empty array. This is what is confusing me - the code works fine when it is first called but not at all when called the second time after the custom cell Action has been triggered.

Here is my viewDidLoad if it helps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _exercises = [NSMutableArray array];
    _totalSets = [NSMutableArray array];
    _currentSets = [NSMutableArray array];
    _totalReps = [NSMutableArray array];

    _titleLabel.text = _workoutName;
    _exercisesTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    [self getData];
}
```

_workoutName is given a value in prepareForSegue in the previous view controller.

Comment: Are your `NSMutableArray` properties instantiating? If so what are their values as you step through your code?

Comment: They populate as expected the first time getData is called (from viewDidLoad) however as soon as the button in the custom cell is pressed and the IBAction in ActiveWorkoutCell.m is triggered, they become nil.

Comment: Your IBActions create new copies of the ActiveWorkOutViewController.  Those new copies are not presented, so viewDidLoad does not run (in those copies).  So the mutable arrays are not initialised.

Comment: @pbasdf could you explain this a bit more and how I should fix it?

Comment: This line: `ActiveWorkoutViewController *vc = [[ActiveWorkoutViewController alloc] init];` creates a new instance of ViewController.  You need instead to access the existing instance.  There are several ways - easiest I think to add a `delegate` property to the custom cell, set the value of `delegate` to `self` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and then use `self.delegate` in place of `vc` in your IBAction methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue. You are instantiating the "ActivityWorkOutViewController" when the IBAction methods called and it will be a new instance and then in those methods you are calling [self getData] which pointing to the new instance which has no variables instantiated or viewDidLoad happened, so your mutable arrays are not allocated and hence they are empty.

Just use the old instance of the class to get the data.

I am not sure how you are referencing those classes. I am just in a confusion about that. But, you might check the allocations and calling the right class to get the data

Comment: As I have now edited my post to include, the code works fine when it is first run from viewDidLoad, so that's not the problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer - how do I use the old instance of the class? (I don't have a good understanding of OOP in Objective-C)

Comment: is "ViewController.m" is "ActivityWorkoutController" you are referencing in the above question ? if so, create a delegate methods on Cell class and use those on ActivityWorkoutController class to call [self getData] method in those delegate methods. so that it will use the existing class.